# Prints sent to redirected remote desktop printers do not print

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, printing, printer

I have an HP Photosmart 7510 printer attached to my workstation (Windows 8.1 x64) that is functioning properly.  I RDP into a 2012 R2 x64 server and print a simple string from notepad.exe to the redirected printer but nothing is printed.  In the Event Viewer under App & Services Logs>Microsoft>Windows>PrintService>Admin I see the following.

```
The document Print Document, owned by russ.speight, failed to print on
printer HP Photosmart 7510 series (redirected 2). Try to print the document 
again, or restart the print spooler. Data type: RAW. Size of the spool 
file in bytes: 46978. Number of bytes printed: 46978. Total number of pages
in the document: 1. Number of pages printed: 0. Client computer: 
\\RemoteWindows2012Server. Win32 error code returned by the print processor:
2147500037. Unspecified error
```

On my local machine I configured the printer to retain print jobs.  An SPL file for the print job is created in c:\windows\system32\spool\printers but it only contains <ctrl>E<esc>%-12345X, where <> are control characters. Googling the sequence shows up as an HP print job language (PJL) command.  The SPL file for the same print operation performed locally is wildly different (45K versus 1k of data).

I've attempted many of the solutions available online:  altering the printer redirection group policies to force use of the native driver or the Easy Print driver; enable/disable the "Render print jobs on client" under the printer's Sharing tab; switching around the printer's Print Process data types.  I've tried a different printer (Ithaca iTerm 280 receipt printer, though this doesn't even drop an SPL file).  I found [this very similar post](https://serverfault.com/questions/573594/remote-desktop-easy-print-not-printing-on-hp-gdi-printers) but I've confirmed both systems already have the referred to patch.

At this point my menial printer troubleshooting skills have been exhausted.  The direct solution would obviously be welcome, but suggestions of here-to-fore-unknown trace files and troubleshooting techniques and tools is what I'm expecting.

Please let me know what points I can clarify.  Much thanks in advance.

Edit:  I forgot to mention that the scenario has been attempted between different client/server pairs but not by me.  I'm waiting on the details of those tests and will post once available.

Edit 2:  The prior tests were conducted using a local Windows 7 Pro SP1 with a Samsung M288x Series printer RDPing into a Windows 8.1 Pro system.

Edit 3:  The objective of the situation is to allow some custom software running on a remote system to output to locally attached receipt printers in a point-of-service style scenario.  I'm currently unaware of how much leeway the company has in workarounds such as creating a printer network share.

Comment: Russell, welcome to server fault. This is a very well formed question. Unfortunately I don't know the answer. Have you, by chance, read our help page on [How to ask a good question?](serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) I'm conducting a survey.

Comment: Thank you, @BigHomie.  I did read it.  It was displayed before allowing me to create the post, though glancing over the guidelines a second time shows that I forgot to include the Why of the problem :-P

Comment: Have you checked if using printers with generic PDL drivers (PCL3, PCL5, PCL6, PostScript 2/3) does help your printing problems? It is a good idea to somewhat narrow down the search field. It does not *have* to be an issue with TS EasyPrint and GDI, but it might be.

Comment: I haven't.  I'll give it a try and report back.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not looking for advanced printing functions, try installing the printer locally with the simplest driver that comes pre-installed, HP Deskjet 600 for example, but make sure your server has the same driver pre-installed.